SED replace value in prisma schema
Assuming I have a file called schema.prisma that looks like this
generator client {
 provider = "prisma-client-js"
}

datasource db {
  provider = somevalue
  url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
}

model User {
  id        Int     @id @default(autoincrement())
  email     String      @unique
  name      String?
  todos     Todo[]
  createdAt DateTime    @default(now())
  updatedAt DateTime    @updatedAt
}

model Todo {
  id        Int     @id @default(autoincrement())
  createdAt DateTime    @default(now())
  updatedAt DateTime    @updatedAt
  title     String      @db.VarChar(255)
  completed Boolean     @default(false)
  user      User        @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id])
  userId    Int
}

And I want to use SED to replace the second provider instance
I have crafted the following regex that gets me the line I want
\bprovider(?!.*prisma).*/

But I just can't seem to get SED to work with it
For example
sed 's/\bprovider\(?!.*prisma\)/blue/' ./prisma/schema.prisma

Should produce
generator client {
 provider = "prisma-client-js"
}

datasource db {
  provider = blue
... rest of file

I know sed reads line by line so this approach to me seems like it should work.
What am I missing with this regex?

sed have no look around capabilities.

Different tools use different variants of regex syntax, and your regex uses features sed doesn't support. See "Why does my regular expression work in X but not in Y?"

Do you actually want to replace the provider value in the 2nd block just because it's the second block or because that block starts with datasource or because it contains the value somevalue or because it doesn't contain the value prisma or something else?

You could try matching a known pattern before the second occurrence:
Using sed
$ sed -E '/^datasource db \{/{n;s/(= ).*/\1blue/}' input_file
generator client {
 provider = "prisma-client-js"
}

datasource db {
  provider = blue
  url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
}

model User {
  id        Int     @id @default(autoincrement())
  email     String      @unique
  name      String?
  todos     Todo[]
  createdAt DateTime    @default(now())
  updatedAt DateTime    @updatedAt
}

model Todo {
  id        Int     @id @default(autoincrement())
  createdAt DateTime    @default(now())
  updatedAt DateTime    @updatedAt
  title     String      @db.VarChar(255)
  completed Boolean     @default(false)
  user      User        @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id])
  userId    Int

Or you could null data the entire file with the -z flag matching the second occurrence of provider.
$ sed -Ez 's/(([^=]*provider = ){2})[^\n]*/\1blue/' input_file


This might work for you (GNU sed):
sed '/provider =/{/prisma/!s/=.*/= blue/}' file

If the line contains provider but not prisma, replace everything following = with = blue.
N.B. In this case it amends the 2nd provider but it would amend every provider thereafter. To amend only the 2nd provider, use:
sed '/provider =/{x;s/^/x/;x;G;s/=.*\nxx$/= blue/;P;d' file


There are a lot of different things you might really be trying to do (see my comment) including any of these, using any awk:
$ awk '($1 == "provider") && c++ { sub(/=.*/,"= blue") } 1' file
generator client {
 provider = "prisma-client-js"
}

datasource db {
  provider = blue
  url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
}

model User {
  id        Int     @id @default(autoincrement())
  email     String      @unique
  name      String?
  todos     Todo[]
  createdAt DateTime    @default(now())
  updatedAt DateTime    @updatedAt
}

model Todo {
  id        Int     @id @default(autoincrement())
  createdAt DateTime    @default(now())
  updatedAt DateTime    @updatedAt
  title     String      @db.VarChar(255)
  completed Boolean     @default(false)
  user      User        @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id])
  userId    Int
}


$ awk 'BEGIN{RS=""; ORS="\n\n"; FS=OFS="\n"} NR==2{ $2="  provider = blue" } 1' file
generator client {
 provider = "prisma-client-js"
}

datasource db {
  provider = blue
  url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
}

model User {
  id        Int     @id @default(autoincrement())
  email     String      @unique
  name      String?
  todos     Todo[]
  createdAt DateTime    @default(now())
  updatedAt DateTime    @updatedAt
}

model Todo {
  id        Int     @id @default(autoincrement())
  createdAt DateTime    @default(now())
  updatedAt DateTime    @updatedAt
  title     String      @db.VarChar(255)
  completed Boolean     @default(false)
  user      User        @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id])
  userId    Int
}


$ awk -v RS= -v ORS='\n\n' '/^datasource db/{ sub(/provider = [^\n]+/,"provider = blue") } 1' file
generator client {
 provider = "prisma-client-js"
}

datasource db {
  provider = blue
  url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
}

model User {
  id        Int     @id @default(autoincrement())
  email     String      @unique
  name      String?
  todos     Todo[]
  createdAt DateTime    @default(now())
  updatedAt DateTime    @updatedAt
}

model Todo {
  id        Int     @id @default(autoincrement())
  createdAt DateTime    @default(now())
  updatedAt DateTime    @updatedAt
  title     String      @db.VarChar(255)
  completed Boolean     @default(false)
  user      User        @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id])
  userId    Int
}

